# Match between two cells if values is in a range VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm struggling in VBA because I want to compare two cells in order to check if there is a partial match between them. But I want to remove the entities that are not common to both cells through list in a range. 
For instance I've my list within range of cells where I've postprocessed the common attribute :

```
Paul 
Pierre 
John 
Henry 
Jack
```

And what I want is to match between two cells where the name are separated with a coma:

```
Cell1 : Paul, Pierre,Rob
Cell2 : Paul,Jack,Rob
```

The result expected when apply this function should be:

```
Cell3 with function : Paul
```

As of now this what I have:

```
  Function Matching(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
     Dim vArr1
     Dim vArr2
     Dim vTest
     Dim lngCnt As Long
     vArr1 = Split(Replace(str1, " ", vbNullString), ",")
     vArr2 = Split(Replace(str2, " ", vbNullString), ",")
     On Error GoTo strExit
     For lngCnt = LBound(vArr1) To UBound(vArr1)
         vTest = Application.Match(vArr1(lngCnt), vArr2, 0)
         If Not IsError(vTest) Then Matching= Matching& vArr1(lngCnt) & ", "
     Next lngCnt
     If Len(Matching) > 0 Then
         Matching= Left$(Matching, Len(Matching) - 2)
     Else
         strExit:
         Matching= "No Matches!"
     End If

 End Function
```

It's working between the two cells taken as argument, meaning that the remaining task is to select the range containing the common attribute in order to remove the entities which are not common..
Hope i was clear, thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have done a good job of explaining what you want and what you have done, but failed to ask a specific question. If you need help on [ask], check out the [help].

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't understand macros completely, however I feel that the question is complete and specific when the OP says *I want to compare two cells in order to check if there is a partial match between them* - Don't you think?

Comment: @Prasanna You prove my point, we are assuming that is the question. Therefore, the need for specific questions so we can respond appropriately. :-)

Comment: I agree @CharlieRB ; Polin- I've altered my answer to address what it is you want to do

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are the inputs? How are they input? How many inputs are there? What's the output?

Comment: I've 3 input, the first two are: Cells(Which contain the attributes separate with a comma) and the last one is a range with all the common attributes. So, in the cells where i enter my function i want to select the two cells + the range. The result expected is to have the common attribute of the two the cells that are also include in the range